# Continue a command on the next line

Tags: autoit

Is there a way to continue a command on a new line? My `MsgBox()` function call is long, for the sake of readability I want to do something like this:

```
$confirm = MsgBox(321, "Check Information", "Confirmation Number:     " & @LF &
                                            "Amount:                  $")
```

This returns a syntax error and points to the end of the first line as being the location of the error.

Comment: Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338176/split-large-string-using-autoit/44339495#44339495), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228798/cant-figure-out-how-to-declare-a-string-array-on-multiple-lines/27233968#27233968).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Place an underscore at the end of the line:

```
$confirm = msgbox(321, "Check Information", "Confirmation Number:     " & @LF & _
                                            "Amount:                  $")
```