# Can't figure out how to declare a string array on multiple lines

Tags: arrays, string, autoit

This code was causing errors *at runtime* but *would* compile.

```
Local $acceptable[] = ["Chrome",_
                        "Firefox",_
                        "IE"]
```

It works if I move it all on one line. However, I want to declare many elements. How do I correctly declare it over multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Language Reference - Comments](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_comments.htm) (emphasis added):

> Although only one statement per line is allowed, a long statement can span multiple lines if an underscore "`_`" **preceded by a blank** is placed at the end of a "broken" line. String definition cannot be split in several lines, concatenation need to be used.

Example (<kbd>space</kbd> before each underscore):

```
#include <Array.au3>

Global Const $g_aAcceptable[] = ["Chrome", _
                                 "Firefox", _
                                 "IE"]

_ArrayDisplay($g_aAcceptable)
```